# style of axis with Highcharts

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I want to change the style of my xAxis and yAxis so as to have some things like in the picture 1 (dotted and not as tha classic one picture 2)

[image]

[image]

Comment: You say xAxis, but it looks pretty normal, what in particular are you having problems with? Or is it the dotted yAxis that is giving you problems?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to be more specific about what you want, and what you're having trouble with.

Comment: I want to have a graphic like picture 1 not like picture i have test by doing some modification but i never get the same graphic like in picture one (dotted and with)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update your width of line by [lineWidth](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.lineWidth) parameter on xAxis/yAxis.

Comment: i have already test with lineWidth but it does not give me the graphic as i want (like in the picture)